# File path in Azure Notebooks

Tags: python, azure-notebooks

I have some data file(.csv) in a folder in Azure notebooks. When I try to open the files on a notebook with the file path its still not finding the file.

I tried `pd.read_csv('project/data/mydata.csv')`

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

It would have been much easier to understand the problem is if you could show your directory structure. But think referring this git issue will be sufficient. If this doesn't help please add the directory structure of your project.

https://github.com/Microsoft/AzureNotebooks/issues/202#issuecomment-335340286